# How to get a unique model instances, not values, using distinct?

Tags: django, django-queryset

### Edit

I have several records with the same field value. I need to filter the queryset to get the model instances contains the **unique field record**, not just a values in the queryset.
**How to filter queryset to keep the instances contains only the unique values of the one field?**

```
>>> dist = Language.objects.distinct()
>>> for i in dist:
>>>     print i.language     
>>> English
>>> English

>>> dist = Language.objects.values('language').distinct()
>>> for i in dist:
>>>     print i['language']     
>>> English
```

Comment: Hmm... why do you have duplicates in the 'language' field of `Language` model? And more importantly, if you have N `Language` with same 'language', which one are you going to need in the distinct result?

Comment: `Model.object.all()` already returns unique instances. It's only when you start to combine several models into one query that you might get duplicates. They will still be unique Python object instances though.

Comment: Oh, I see. I reformulated the question.

Comment: @BéresBotond, the answer for your first question is too long) sorry. I do not care which of the instances will be obtained, it is important to the lack of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way, but the first thing that comes to mind is this:

```
ids = (lang['max_id'] for lang in Language.objects.values('language').annotate(max_id=Max('pk')))
results = Language.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
```

Basically grouping by language and picking the field record with highest ID for each language.